# Bash - Extract filenames without extensions and check if identically named files with a different extension exist

Tags: bash

I have two folders with many files of the same naming format but differing extensions. I would like to loop through the files of the first folder and extract their filenames to check if a file of the same name exists in the other folder, then create one (with the other extension) if it doesn't. I can't get a grapple on bash for whatever reason, so I was wondering if there's a simple way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, have fun coding it!  Jokes aside, you need to loop on the result of a `find` (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, with option `-print0`), then remove the extension (look at variable expansion), then do another `find` with option `-name "filename.*"`.

Comment: Do files in the first folder have extensions or are they just filenames?